# If a bluetooth device has no linux support is it legal to write your own driver?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, driver, sensors

I am looking into a senor that has bluetooth connectivity and proprietary software for mac os and windows but know drivers or software for Linux. Is it legal to look at the signals passed over bluetooth (without reverse engineering the existing software) to figure out how to communicate with the device?

Answer (score 1):

It's legal in the US and the EU at the very least.  See WP's [Reverse Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering#Reverse_engineering_of_machines) article for more details on applicable laws.

A *Linux* or *BSD* user may not know that they're running a reverse-engineered hardware driver.  For example, WP's [Comparison of open-source wireless drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_wireless_drivers#Status), under the "*Developement*" column, shows over a dozen reverse-engineered wifi drivers.